# Oracle ORDS expose packaged procedure with parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

I'm trying to expose oracle packaged procedure via Oracle ORDS but getting 404 error.

My package

```
create or replace PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE AS  -- define the package spec
 TYPE userChanges IS RECORD
(
    id number(32,0),
    partner_id varchar2(256 byte),
    application_user varchar2(256 byte),
    application_name varchar2(256 byte),
    transaction_start timestamp(6) with local time zone, 
    transaction_end timestamp(6) with local time zone , 
    service_id varchar2(256 byte), 
    exec_time number(32,0), 
    error_code varchar2(256 byte),
    operation varchar2(256 byte), 
    type varchar2(512 byte), 
    name varchar2(256 byte),
    value varchar2(4000 byte)
);

TYPE userTable IS TABLE OF userChanges
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE GetUserSnapShot(P_START_TIME in timestamp, 
                        P_END_TIME  in timestamp, 
                        P_MAX_ROWS  in int,
                        myTable in out userTable);
END MY_PACKAGE;
```

Package body

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE AS  -- define the package body
 PROCEDURE getusersnapshot(P_START_TIME in timestamp, 
                        P_END_TIME  in timestamp, 
                        P_MAX_ROWS  in int,
                        myTable in out userTable)
 AS
   rec  userChanges; 
BEGIN
rec.id := 1;
rec.partner_id    := 'test';
rec.application_user   := 'ABCDEF';
rec.application_name := 'ddd';
rec.transaction_start   := SYSDATE;
rec.transaction_end   := SYSDATE;
rec.service_id   := 'ddd';
rec.exec_time   := 2;
rec.error_code   := 'dddd';
rec.operation   := 'ddd';
rec.type   := 'ddd';
rec.name   := 'ddd';
rec.value   := 'ddd';
myTable(1) := rec;
END;
END MY_PACKAGE;
```

This package enabled rest service via SQL developer which execute following sql.

```
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN

ORDS.ENABLE_OBJECT(p_enabled => TRUE,
                   p_schema => 'TESTUSER',
                   p_object => 'MY_PACKAGE',
                   p_object_type => 'PACKAGE',
                   p_object_alias => 'my_package',
                   p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);

commit;
END;
```

This execute successfully.

My URL for POST is http://localhost:8083/ords/testuser/my_package/getusersnapshot with body `{}` as i testing.
This gives error 404.
But when i execute package with procedure without parameters it works fine. What is the problem i have here ?

Comment: Try http://localhost:8083/ords/testuser/my_package/GETUSERSNAPSHOT

Comment: I have an example here https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/08/executing-pl-sql-package-procedure-via-rest/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thanks and yes said url is working. Got 500 error `INFO: Error occurred while binding parameter at index: 4 for statment: [CALL, begin  "MY_PACKAGE"."GETUSERSNAPSHOT"(  /*in:P_START_TIME*/?,
 /*in:P_END_TIME*/?,  /*in:P_MAX_ROWS*/?,  /*inout:MYTABLE*/? );
end;, [P_MAX_ROWS, in, interface oracle.dbtools.raptor.datatypes.DataValue], [P_START_TIME, in, interface oracle.dbtools.raptor.datatypes.DataValue], [P_END_TIME, in, interface oracle.dbtools.raptor.datatypes.DataValue], [MYTABLE, inout, interface oracle.dbtools.raptor.datatypes.DataValue]]. Any idea what is wrong data type ?

Comment: Check your date values, they should be zulu formatted...see how ords outputs a date and then mirror that format. Show us your post body json